# Why is the title of a question linked to the same page?

Tags: support, questions, hyperlinks

I already asked a related [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26254170/linked-blog-post-titles). Please see the reference.

What's the benefit especially for the Stack Exchange network to link the title to the same permanent page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be very many links that link to the same page. For example, each answer and comment has it's own unique url. So if you are under that url, but just want to copy/paste the question url, you can just click on that link to get the correct link you want to copy paste from the address bar.

For example, this is the link to @Doorknob's comment on your question.

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242210/why-is-the-title-of-a-question-linked-to-the-same-page/242211#comment791897_242210
```

and this is the link to my answer on your question

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242211/244519
```

So if I wanted to share the link of your question in a chat room or another post on the SE network, but didn't want the page to go to @Doorknob's comment or my answer first, but just load the page normally starting with the question at the top, I would just use this url :

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242210/why-is-the-title-of-a-question-linked-to-the-same-page
```

However, if I wanted to link to your question/this thread somewhere else on the internet, like Reddit, I would use this url

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242210/244519
                                       ^^^ my UserId, so your's would include yours when you click on share in your question
```

Because you can get badges, like the [Announcer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/74/announcer) for bringing others to the site.

Comment: Ok, I see. This seems pretty legitimately for services (like this) with comment functions and also for pages with linked sub-headings to jump to those. But in the most cases the links to the comments are only sub-links of the original post/question. Only `/242211#242211` is added to the end of the URL of my question for your answer.

Comment: While this may be a legit reason, I find it annoying because it makes it harder to copy text from the title.